# Use of unassignment variable event when is assigned?

Tags: c#, .net

The following code is not compiling in my VS 2017:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < data.data.Length; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[0, i].Value = data.data[i].name;
            Type type;

            try
            {
                type = Type.GetType((string)data.data[i].type);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}

            for (int j = 0; j < data.data[i].data.Count; j++)
            {
                ws.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = Convert.ChangeType(data.data[i].data[j], type);
            }
        }
```

The following line is returning this error: `Use of unassigned local variable 'type'`:

```
ws.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = Convert.ChangeType(data.data[i].data[j], type);
```

I would like to know how to fix it, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `type` can be unassigned under some particular conditions. In this case, you only assigned `type` in the `try` statement. What if an exception is thrown in the `try` statement and so `type` is never assigned?

You need to assign `type` before the `try` statement, or just halt if an exception occurs.

```
Type type = null; // assigning null fixes the error but this might not be a good solution.

try
{
    type = Type.GetType((string)data.data[i].type);
}
```

You need to think carefully about what you want to do if there is an exception. If there is an exception `type` will be unassigned and your code might not be able to proceed. If that applies to your situation, I suggest you to show an error message in the `catch` statement and `return`.

Basically, having an empty catch statement is generally a *really* bad idea.

Comment: If the catch executes I'm ignoring because the `data.data[I].type` is something that the user can send, and if he sends something that is not valid I and use the default one - System.String

Answer (score 0):

the try catch can fail and then `type` won't be initiazlized.

as a minimal example

```
Type type;
try
{
    type = typeof(int);

}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
Console.WriteLine($"{type}");
```

the writeline will fail with the same compiler error

either initialize it 
with `Type type = null`

or don't let the code get there out of the catch

Comment: Would be possible to test if type is assigned, or something like that?

Comment: in your catch you may want to go `continue`  and then it will carry on in the for loop

Comment: The compiler is that smart to detect possible undeclared variables @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're see is that `type` has not been initialised. Change the declaration to `Type type = null;`.

Then you can use `if (type != null)` around the `for` loop to ensure that `type` has actually been set.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that `type` assignment is enclosed into a `try-catch block` and that `Type.GetType((string)data.data[i].type)` can throw an exception... if an exception occurs, your `type` variable will unassigned and, hence, the inner for loop will try to pass an unassigned value to `Convert.ChangeType`. You have to possible solutions to avoid this.

The first one consists of skipping the current outer cycle if an exception is thrown:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.data.Length; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[0, i].Value = data.data[i].name;

    Type type;

    try
    {
        type = Type.GetType((string)data.data[i].type);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < data.data[i].data.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = Convert.ChangeType(data.data[i].data[j], type);
    }
}
```

The second one consists of pre-initializing your `type` variable with `null`... but, honestly, I don't know what happens if you pass a `null` to `Convert.ChangeType`... probably something bad or maybe nothing (just a waste of inner cycles):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.data.Length; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[0, i].Value = data.data[i].name;

    Type type = null;

    try
    {
        type = Type.GetType((string)data.data[i].type);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    for (int j = 0; j < data.data[i].data.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = Convert.ChangeType(data.data[i].data[j], type);
    }
}
```